# require 'celluloid' takes a long time to load

Tags: ruby, jruby, celluloid, secure-random

I have a JRuby application deployed on Google compute engine. I noticed that it takes a while to load the `celluloid` gem. After looking into more details, I found that it is taking more time to load `celluloid/internals/stack`.

Usually, it takes more than 2 mins. Once it even took around 41 mins to load that. The server has a good configuration with 15Gb RAM and 4 cores.

JAVA version

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

JRUBY version

```
jruby 9.0.5.0 (2.2.3) 2016-01-26 7bee00d Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.74-b02 on 1.8.0_74-b02 +jit [linux-amd64]
```

[image]

---

When I tried same with ruby it loads `celluloid` quickly.

Comment: You could make a screenshot on a mac with command+shift+3 or screenshot part of the screen with command+shift+4

Comment: Updated my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Install `haveged` to replenish entropy faster on virtual machines.

You probably don't have enough entropy to generate `UUID`'s pulled from  `SecureRandom` which under `jRuby` runs out of randomness easily. Especially on virtual machines. So your virtual machine is literally waiting for more randomness to be possible. `haveged` helps replenish that randomness lightening fast by collecting new kinds of entropy.

### Installing...

Download: http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/downloads.html

Under Debian-like Linux flavors like Mint and Ubuntu, this gets that done:

```
sudo apt-get install haveged
```

---

### This is a known issue with `SecureRandom` under `jRuby` ...

In the past I had this issue also, and had to use `strace` to locate the issue. Notice this file, which is the one loaded just before the line you mentioned in your question ... [`internals/uuid.rb`](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-essentials/blob/master/lib/celluloid/internals/uuid.rb):

```
require "securerandom"

module Celluloid
  module Internals
    # Clearly Ruby doesn't have enough UUID libraries
    # This one aims to be fast and simple with good support for multiple threads
    # If there's a better UUID library I can use with similar multithreaded
    # performance, I certainly wouldn't mind using a gem for this!
    module UUID
      values = SecureRandom.hex(9).match(/(.{8})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})/)
      PREFIX = "#{values[1]}-#{values[2]}-4#{values[3]}-8#{values[4]}".freeze

      #de ...
    end
  end
end
```

That was the offending code, because it generates a `9` hex-digit string which it can use as a prefix for `UUID` codes... using `SecureRandom`.

Then later, there are uses of that via the `Celluloid::Internals::UUID.generate` method. But at load-time, the `Celluloid::Internals::UUID` module performs operations which require `SecureRandom` ... which `jRuby` has had trouble with:

- https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3351
- https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1896
- https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1405

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help

Comment: I understand this would be non-blocking but could you elaborate more on this? Not sure but will this cause any issues later? I just want to understand more on this problem.

Comment: If you have `haveged` installed on the system you are running `Celluloid` on, and this solved the issue for you, the issue will not resurface. When `Celluloid` starts, it pulls in a series of random characters to use in making a `UUID` and that operation *is* a blocking operation, before `Celluloid` even starts anything or really instantiates anything. If you're curious of the exact place this happens, I can come back and add that to my answer in the near future.

Comment: Every `*nix` computer is aways storing entropy it receives -- which is usually from keystrokes, mouse movements, even network traffic -- but those sources of entropy are next to nothing for virtual machines which have no user at the keyboard. `haveged` uses a special approach that turns the running processes on the machine into a source of entropy, which is perfect for virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I would like to know exact place this happens. Please update answer with it whenever you get a chance.

Comment: But why that didn't happen when I tried same in Ruby?

Comment: You should research `SecureRandom` and it's differences on `jRuby`